# Get type of class field with null value in Haxe

Tags: class, types, metaprogramming, haxe, neko

Is it possible to get class of field with null value in haxe?

The function "Type.getClass" gets class of value (setted at runtime), but I need to get class defined in a compilation-time.

Function "getClassFields" returns only names of fields, without classes.

For example:

```
class MyCls
{
   public static var i:Int = null;
   public static var s:String = null;
}

trace(Type.getClass(MyCls.i)); // show "null", but I need to get Int
trace(Type.getClass(MyCls.s)); // show "null", but I need to get String
```

And in my situation I can't to change sources of class MyCls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to get the types for null fields, you really need to resort to Haxe's Runtime Type Information (RTTI) (as @ReallylUniqueName recomended).

```
import haxe.rtti.Rtti;
import haxe.rtti.CType;

class Test {
    static function main()
    {
        if (!Rtti.hasRtti(MyCls))
            throw "Please add @:rtti to class";
        var rtti = Rtti.getRtti(MyCls);
        for (sf in rtti.statics)
            trace(sf.name, sf.type, CTypeTools.toString(sf.type));
    }
}
```

*Now, obviously, there's a catch...*

RTTI requires a `@:rtti` metadata, but you said you cannot change the `MyCls` class to add it.  The solution then is do add it through a macro in your build file.  For instance, if you're using a `.hxml` file, it should then look like:

```
--interp
--macro addMetadata("@:rtti", "MyCls")
-main Test
```

With this and your own `MyCls` definition, the output would look like:

```
Test.hx:11: i,CAbstract(Int,{ length => 0 }),Int
Test.hx:11: s,CClass(String,{ length => 0 }),String
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `Runtime Type Information`. It's a Haxe feature which allow go get full description of a type in runtime.
http://haxe.org/manual/cr-rtti.html